# How to set the coordinate system?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have a class `MaskGraphicsWidget.cpp` inheriting from `QGraphicsView` which contains several functions, the constructor is:

```
 MaskGraphicsWidget::MaskGraphicsWidget(QTreeWidget * tree, QWidget* parent) : QGraphicsView(parent), m_tree_widget(tree){
     setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
     setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
     m_mask_scene = new QGraphicsScene;
     m_mask_scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 250, 250);
     setScene(m_mask_scene);
     primitive = 0;
     minX = 0;
     minY = 0;
}
```

where I initialize my scene `m_mask_scene` and I set the coordinate system.

I also have a function `MousePressEvent` :

`http://pastebin.com/wjwDTQzw`

And my `MaskGraphicsWidget.h` is like that :

```
QGraphicsScene* m_mask_scene;
QList<QPointF> m_polygon_points;
QList<QGraphicsLineItem*> m_polygon_lines;
int minX; 
int minY;
```

My problem is that, I want to set the Pos of the `QGraphicsPolygonItem poly` but if I set it to the value `min` and `max` (that I calculate somewhere else), the item moves from the current Pos to the Pos of `min` and `max`. Basically it sets the Pos of the item in his own coordinate system. How can I write that I want to set the Pos in the coordinate system of the `m_mask_scene` ?
Sorry for my English, if you did not understand, feel free to add a comment !

Edit 1 :

`m_polygon_points` and `m_polygon_lines` are filled somewhere else and it's working. (see `pastebin`)

Edit 2 : Added the plan, see below for better (I hope) understanding !

[image: Plan]

Explanation of the plan : the black polygon is what I got (I do not set any Pos), but if I do set the Pos at `min` and `max`, I get the red polygon. I want to set the Pos at `min` and `max` AND still have the black polygon ! Sorry for my poor paint skills

Edit 3 : Of course, if I print the Pos of the `QGraphicsPolygonItem poly`, it shows `(0,0)`.

Edit 4 : Added a pastebin to not overload the post, I've put everything in it, please ignore the `PrimitiveItem` things, and the `case` 0 and 1 which are not for the `QGraphicsPolygonItem`.

Edit 5 : To clarify, I catch the event on `MousePressEvent`:

- if it's a left click, I use it to create a new point (creating new lines for my polygon)
- if it's a right click, I don't use the event but instead I just close my polygon, delete all the lines added to the scene and adding the polygon in the scene.

Comment: When a QGraphicsItem is added to a scene, a call to the item's setPos will set the position, relative to its parent (in this case, the scene). The line poly->setPos(poly->pos()); in your case does nothing. If you want assistance showing why setting the values min and max for the position isn't working, I suggest you show the code where they are calculated and how you're setting the position.

Comment: Yeah you're right the line does nothing but I was like "I'm lost, can't solve the problem on my own". I'm adding right now where min and max are calculated. Thanks for your answer ! But i'm not setting any position on my QGraphicsPolygonItem poly ...

Comment: (other than the line that does nothing !)

Comment: You define MaskGraphicsWidget::mousePressEvent twice. Firstly, creating a polygon item and then setting the values minX and minY. If this is the same function, please update your question to show the function in its entirety, not as two separate fragments. I expect the problem is that you've misunderstood that the origin of the polygon item is the top left of the object.

Comment: There are a lot of lines in the function so I didn't want to post all of this there. I'm doing it right now. Created a pastebin to not overload the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
 QPointF point(event->x(), event->y());
```

With *event* being a QMouseEvent, a call to x() and y() [returns coordinates relative to the widget that receives the event.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html#pos) In this case, MaskGraphicsWidget, which is a [QGraphicsView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html).

If you add an item to a scene and want to set its position, you're setting its position relative to its parent. In the case of an item with no parent, the position is relative to the scene (in scene coordinates).

So your current code is trying to set view coordinates, not scene coordinates. You need to convert the position of the mouse coordinates to the scene: -

```
QPointF scenePoint = mapToScene(event->pos());
```

Then use this to set the position of the newly created item.

Note that a QGraphicsView is like a window looking into a world (the QGraphicsScene), so it may not match the scene coordinates.

Comment: I don't use the `event` on the right click because it doesn't matter where I right click, I just want to close my polygon (by adding the first one again at the end of the `QVector`) and set the Pos. I tried with `QPointF scenePoint = mapToScene(event->pos()); poly->setPos(scenePoint);` but it moves the polygon (like in the plan, I get the red one). Both the scene and the view have the same coordinates (0,0,250,250). Thanks for your answer !

Comment: "I don't use the event on the right click...." - I suggest you read this and alter your question appropriately: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think you missunderstood what I want to do, my English is probably in fault, I'll read what you linked and alter my question after.